# ng-bind-html does not load image src

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple presentation like this

```
<div id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in itemList">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.html"></div>
</div>
```

The item.html contains html like this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="icons/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"/></a>
```

However, the resulting html does not load the image:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img alt="Youtube"/></a>
```

After some searching, looks like angularjs does this to avoid cross-site scripting, but i was able to load an image from youtube directly.

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/9bZkp7q19f0/0.jpg" alt="Youtube"/></a>
```

Further more, I was able to load all the images by using ng-bind-html-unsafe.

```
    <div id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in itemList">
        <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="item.html"></div>
    </div>
```

If I use ng-bind-html-unsafe, I don't need the ngSanitize module anymore, meaning my code is less secure? I do have use cases where I load images from external sources.

Coming to my questions:

1. What is the difference between ng-bind-html and ng-bind-html-unsafe apart from what I have mentioned above. Is there any documentation about this? I could not find any.
2. How do I accomplish loading images from the host server and external servers, and not having to use the unsafe directive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. There isn't much more to add to what you said.

   `ng-bind-html` allows you to load HTML content into your angular app after it has been sanitized (using the `$sanitise` service).
   On the other hand, `ng-bind-html-unsafe` allows you to load any HTML content without being sanitized.

   The sanitise process consists on checking each element of the provided HTML content with a list of well known HTML tags/elements. Any tag/element that isn't on the list is then removed. Apart from that there are a few more validations on specific HTML attributes (such as the `src`).

   In your case the element `<img src="icons/youtube.png" alt="Youtube"/>` doesn't have a valid `src` attribute because it doesn't match AngularJS' URI regexp: `/^((ftp|https?):\/\/|mailto:|tel:|#)/`

   For more information check [ngBindHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive%3angBindHtml), [ngBindHtmlUnsafe](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe) and [$sanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.%24sanitize) (and [AngularJS source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js))
2. I believe there isn't... especially if you don't control the HTML you are loading in. As stated on the `ngBindHtmlUnsafe` documentation:

   > You should use this directive only if ngBindHtml directive is too
   >   restrictive and when you absolutely trust the source of the content
   >   you are binding to.

   So, it's all about trusting the source of the HTML content you're loading. In last case you can always process/'sanitise' the HTML content yourself, however that doesn't seem to be easy to accomplish, specially if the content is dynamic.

Comment: I replaced the URI from icons/youtube.png to the full URL http://localhost/test/icons/youtube.png and I was able to use ng-bind-html. Now I am noticing another weird side effect. Using the sanitized version removes inline style information from the div contained in item.html.

Comment: Looked through the $sanitize docs, and looks like this is by design. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

[Nenad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/186822/nenad) answered a question like this recently. By invoking $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html) you will be able to mark the HTML as valid so that ng-bind-html will accept it. Even when the img src is relative and would therefore otherwise be marked as invalid.

[You can find his post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu)