# How do you use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular 1.2+

Tags: angularjs

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` was removed in Angular 1.2

I'm trying to implement something where I need to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`. In the docs and on the github commit they say:

> ng-bind-html provides ng-html-bind-unsafe like behavior (innerHTML's the result without
>   sanitization) when bound to the result of $sce.trustAsHtml(string).

How do you do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML into view using AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

That should be:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
```

plus in your controller:

```
$scope.html = '<ul><li>render me please</li></ul>';
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
```

instead of old syntax, where you could reference `$scope.html` variable directly:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>
```

As several commenters pointed out, `$sce` has to be injected in the controller, otherwise you will get `$sce undefined` error.

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 myApp.controller('MyController', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    // ... [your code]
 }]);
```

Comment: How can you do this with a value returned by a function?

    <p ng-bind-html="">{{description(category.id)}}</p>

Comment: Not sure if I got you right, but:
    `<p ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></p>`

and `$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(description(category.id));`

Comment: I love you for responding! Apparently the issue was me using 1.0.8. I have a form with dynamic number of sections so on change I wanted to show the proper description. `<p ng-bind-html="description(category.id)"></p>` then the last line of the function: `return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);`

Comment: But...
  var x = sce.trustAsHtml('foo'); var y = sce.trustAsHtml('foo'); x==y;
false
... So shouldn't this create an infinite digest loop since your function returns a new object ?

Comment: To answer my own comment, this was fixed in master:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4087
Angular (as of today, anyway) compares the toString value, not the object reference.

Comment: Just a notice: there is non need to declare html and trustedHtml apart, is simply a matter of marking the data using $sce.trustAsHtml(), so is simple as declaring: $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(theHTML)… anyway, thank you!

Comment: Also worth mentioning is $sce needs to be passed into the controller or you get $sce is not defined

Comment: @Nenad, can scope variables be used here `$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html <--inside html, that is marked as trusted);`

Comment: make sure to add dependency on ngSanitize to your module.

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is deprecated.

Comment: how can i use this in an array of strings .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299635/apply-strong-tags-to-a-string-in-my-js-coffee-file

Comment: How to do this for summernote editor, initially i will get the json data(which contains html) from server, in summernote i am using ng-model. how to make the code as trusted to display in summernote editor

Comment: @Abaij I added additional description in the answer. You have to inject `$sce` in the controller.

Comment: Don't you need a comma before the first square bracket? `'MyController, '['$sce', function($sce) `

Comment: Left insert sanitize <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-sanitize.min.js" "></script>

Comment: Or make one line in your controller: `$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml('<ul><li>render me please</li></ul>');`

Comment: @hawkeye That would be incorrect code. You want to attach `trustedHtml` to the `$scope`, so it's exposed in the template HTML markup.

Answer (score 639):

**Filter**

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

**Usage**

```
<ANY ng-bind-html="value | unsafe"></ANY>
```

Comment: Why do you need `ngSanitize` here?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh because the $sce service is defined in ngSanitize.  they broke apart major functionality so we can use angular just a little bit and not always have to use the entire framework.

Comment: I've been wondering what the security implications of something like this might be? I've asked for more clarification in [a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144546/angular-sce-vs-html-in-external-locale-files). All input appreciated!

Comment: @felix in version 1.2 (when they added this) it is enabled by default as part of core, not `ngSanitize`, so there is no need for `ngSanitize`

Comment: How is app.filter called here - would like some underlying understanding of what is going on. I can see that we might call the function app.filter(value to be cleaned); but is angular doing this behind the scenes with your Usage example ? Thanks

Comment: Ahh I see that filter is specified in this case 'unsafe' and it runs the function. Does anyone know of a good tutorial for this kind of understanding on what this function is doing.
Ok so I can say that the function returns another function I cant see why not just run the line of code why wrap it in another function. And I cant see how val is mapped.

Comment: This is a design decision made by the angular team - that's how filters should be implemented - if you do it otherwise, they won't work.
The reason why this must return a function is that angular can delay processing until it 'finds the right moment'. Otherwise the framework would not have any influence on when the filter is called. That's both good and bad, but as far as I can tell - it's necessary to cope with angulars' tricky processing. More info here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$filterProvider

Comment: I found that I was not able to inject html into a directive that for me is a modal dialogue So the following didnt work !
<modal-dialog show='modalShown' class="{{modalShown}}">
<!--<div my-youtube code="code"></div>-->
<div ng-bind-html="modalContent | unsafe"></div>
</modal-dialog>

So I wanted to reuse the modal by injecting the content depending - sounds reasonable. I am still searching for an elegant modal solution in angular that can handle programatic content swap.

Comment: is it possible to use it with input along with ngmodel

Comment: No need to wrap `$sce.trustAsHtml` in an extra function. You can just `return $sce.trustAsHtml` and save two lines.

Comment: I tried this solution with my custom tag. It seems automatically lost its directive logic and styling for some reason. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: There is no need of `$sce.trustAsHtml`. Just ng-bind-html works perfectly!

Comment: This is really practical as it avoids polluting your controllers with $sce.trusAsHtml

Comment: Since I don't work with Angular often, this would've taken me a while to figure out myself. Thanks a lot, enjoy the bounty.

Comment: How to do this for summernote editor, initially i will get the json data(which contains html) from server, in summernote i am using ng-model. how to make the code as trusted to display in summernote editor

Comment: just to make the filter minfication safe 
 app.filter('unsafe'['$sce', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; }]);

Answer (score 16):

Personally I sanitize all my data with some PHP libraries before going into the database so there's no need for another XSS filter for me.

From AngularJS 1.0.8

```
directives.directive('ngBindHtmlUnsafe', [function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.addClass('ng-binding').data('$binding', attr.ngBindHtmlUnsafe);
        scope.$watch(attr.ngBindHtmlUnsafe, function ngBindHtmlUnsafeWatchAction(value) {
            element.html(value || '');
        });
    }
}]);
```

To use:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="group.description"></div>
```

To disable `$sce`:

```
app.config(['$sceProvider', function($sceProvider) {
    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
}]);
```

Comment: I am unclear what the difference is between the two examples. One of our team members has a problem where they have System.out.println(&ldquo;Hello World!&rdquo;); in the database. She is using <div data-ng-bind-html="text"></div> and it appears on the page as: System.out.println(&ldquo;Hello World!&rdquo;);. Are you saying that using your ngBindHtmlUnsafe directive would fix this problem?

Comment: @Alan I believe it would work if it was `<script>System.out.printIn("Hello World!");</script>`, haven't tried this personally because my PHP removed all JS from user input.  I removed my second example because Angular's native one is superior in every way just use that one.

Comment: How to do this for summernote editor, initially i will get the json data(which contains html) from server, in summernote i am using ng-model. how to make the code as trusted to display in summernote editor

Answer (score 9):

`var line = "<label onclick="alert(1)">aaa</label>";`

#### 1. use filter

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

using (html):

```
<span ng-bind-html="line | unsafe"></span>
==>click `aaa` show alert box
```

#### 2. use ngSanitize : safer

include `angular-sanitize.js`

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

add **`ngSanitize`** in root angular app

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);
```

using (html):

```
<span ng-bind-html="line"></span>
==>click `aaa` nothing happen
```

Comment: How to do this for summernote editor, initially i will get the json data(which contains html) from server, in summernote i am using ng-model. how to make the code as trusted to display in summernote editor

Answer (score 7):

Simply creating a filter will do the trick. (Answered for Angular 1.6)

```
.filter('trustHtml', [
        '$sce',
        function($sce) {
            return function(value) {
                return $sce.trustAs('html', value);
            }
        }
    ]);
```

And use this as follow in the html.

```
<h2 ng-bind-html="someScopeValue | trustHtml"></h2>
```

Comment: This one fixes the error with uglifying: "Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- unsafeFilter"

Answer (score 3):

If you want the old directive back, you can add this to your app:

**Directive:**

```
directives.directive('ngBindHtmlUnsafe', ['$sce', function($sce){
    return {
        scope: {
            ngBindHtmlUnsafe: '=',
        },
        template: "<div ng-bind-html='trustedHtml'></div>",
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.updateView = function() {
                $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.ngBindHtmlUnsafe);
            }

            $scope.$watch('ngBindHtmlUnsafe', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                $scope.updateView(newVal);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

**Usage**

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="group.description"></div>
```

[Source - https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/813](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/813)

Comment: Does not behave the same.

Comment: How to do this for summernote editor, initially i will get the json data(which contains html) from server, in summernote i am using ng-model. how to make the code as trusted to display in summernote editor

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript

```
$scope.get_pre = function(x) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(x);
};
```

HTML

```
<pre ng-bind-html="get_pre(html)"></pre>
```

Comment: How to do this for summernote editor, initially i will get the json data(which contains html) from server, in summernote i am using ng-model. how to make the code as trusted to display in summernote editor

Answer (score 1):

For **Rails** (at least in my case) if you are using the **angularjs-rails gem**, please remember to add the sanitize module

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-sanitize
```

And then load it up in your app...

```
var myDummyApp = angular.module('myDummyApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Then you can do the following:

On the template:

```
%span{"ng-bind-html"=>"phone_with_break(x)"}
```

And eventually:

```
$scope.phone_with_break = function (x) {
  if (x.phone != "") {
   return x.phone + "<br>";
  }
  return '';
}
```

Comment: How to do this for summernote editor, initially i will get the json data(which contains html) from server, in summernote i am using ng-model. how to make the code as trusted to display in summernote editor

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/59#issuecomment-29517163

Answer (score 0):

```
my helpful code for others(just one aspx to do text area post)::

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication45.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

    enter code here

<html ng-app="htmldoc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('htmldoc', ['ngSanitize']).controller('x', function ($scope, $sce) {
            //$scope.htmlContent = '<script> (function () { location = \"http://moneycontrol.com\"; } )()<\/script> In last valid content';
            $scope.htmlContent = '';
            $scope.withoutSanitize = function () {
                return $sce.getTrustedHtml($scope.htmlContent);
            };
            $scope.postMessage = function () {
                var ValidContent = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.htmlContent);

                //your ajax call here
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Example to show posting valid content to server with two way binding
        <div ng-controller="x">
            <p ng-bind-html="htmlContent"></p>
            <textarea ng-model="htmlContent" ng-trim="false"></textarea>
            <button ng-click="postMessage()">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.trustAsHtml=function(scope)
{
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(scope);
}
<p class="card-text w-100" ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(note.redoq_csd_product_lead_note)"></p>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.