# Angular $sce vs HTML in external locale files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xss

A question regarding `ng-bind-html` whilst upgrading an Angular app from 1.0.8 to 1.2.8:

I have locale strings stored in files named `en_GB.json`, `fr_FR.json`, etc. So far, I have allowed the use of HTML within the locale strings to allow the team writing the localized content to apply basic styling or adding inline anchor tags. This would result in the following example JSON:

```
{
  "changesLater":     "<strong>Don't forget</strong> that you can always make changes later." 
  "errorEmailExists": "That email address already exists, please <a href=\"login\">sign in</a> to continue."
}
```

When using these strings with `ng-bind-html="myStr"`, I understand that I now need to use `$sce.trustAsHtml(myStr)`. I could even write a filter as suggested in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705096/619602) which would result in using `ng-bind-html="myStr | unsafe"`.

### Questions:

1. By doing something like this, is my app now insecure? And if so, how might an attacker exploit this?
2. I can understand potential exploits if the source of the displayed HTML string was a user (ie. blog post-style comments that will be displayed to other users), but would my app really be at risk if I'm only displaying HTML from a JSON file hosted on the same domain?
3. Is there any other way I should be looking to achieve the marking-up of externally loaded content strings in an angular app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are not making your app any less secure. You were already inserting HTML in your page with the old method of ng-bind-html-unsafe. You are still doing the same thing, except now you have to explicitly trust the **source** of the HTML rather than just specifying that part of your template can **output** raw HTML. Requiring the use of $sce makes it harder to accidentally accept raw HTML from an untrusted source - in the old method where you only declared the trust in the template, bad input might make its way into your model in ways you didn't think of.
2. If the content comes from your domain, or a domain you control, then you're safe - at least as safe as you can be. If someone is somehow able to highjack the payload of a response from your own domain, then your security is already all manner of screwed. Note, however, you should definitely **not** ever call $sce.trustAsHtml on content that comes from a domain that **isn't** yours.
3. Apart from maintainability concerns, I don't see anything wrong with the way you're doing it. Having a ton of HTML live in a JSON file is maybe not ideal, but as long as the markup is reasonably semantic and not too dense, I think it's fine. If the markup becomes significantly more complex, I'd consider splitting it into separate angular template files or directives as needed, rather than trying to manage a bunch of markup wrapped in JSON strings.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, Alex. All makes sense. As for 3) yes I totally agree, the JSON should only ever contain basic text formatting elements such as `<strong>`, `<p>` or `<span class="foo">`. Come to think of it, is there any way to explicitly trust specific named HTML elements instead of HTML as a whole?

Comment: Looks like $sanitize does something like what you're asking about. If you include it as a dependency, it automatically sanitizes anything bound with ng-bind-html, and "All safe tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to properly escaped html string." Exactly which tokens are on the whitelist, though, I can't find in the documentation. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize.  Note that there's an additional angular-sanitize.js you have to include to use this module.

Comment: In a project I'm doing, I'll be displaying some HTML retrieved from a Google Directions service. I feel like it's probably much more secure than the server the rest of the app will be running on. Is this naive thinking?

Comment: @BryanRayner As a general rule, I'd say do not display un-sanitized HTML from a 3rd party if you can avoid it. No, Google is not going to try to XSS your site. There could be some content you're not anticipating, though, and it could break your design in some unexpected way.