# Bind HTML string with custom style

Tags: angularjs

I want to bind a HTML string with an custom style to the DOM. However `ngSanitize` removes the style from the string.

For example:

*In the controller:*

```
$scope.htmlString = "<span style='color: #89a000'>123</span>!";
```

*And in DOM:*

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="htmlString"></div>
```

Will omit the style attribute. The result will look like:

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="htmlString"><span>123</span>!</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="htmlString"><span style='color: #89a000'>123</span>!</div>
```

**Question:** How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As already mentioned @Beyers, you have to use `$sce.trustAsHtml()`, to use it directly into the DOM, you could do it like this, JS/controller part:

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
};
```

And in DOM/HTML part

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(htmlString)"></div>
```

Comment: I tried your code with the AngularJS version 1.3.15 and it didn't work :(

Comment: I found the Chris's answer with this post and it worked perfectly. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Comment: be carefull, don't use this is if the user can use the input 'string', otherwise you have an XSS

Comment: This variant is nice

Answer (score 51):

What about custom angular filter? This works in 1.3.20

```
angular.module('app.filters')
    .filter('trusted', function($sce){
        return function(html){
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
        }
     })
```

Use it like `<div ng-bind-html="model.content | trusted"></div>`

Comment: This is the better solution

Comment: You, sir, just saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If you trust the html, then you can use [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#methods_trustashtml) to explicitly trust the html.
Quick example:

In controller (remember to inject $sce into your controller):

```
$scope.htmlString = $sce.trustAsHtml("<span style='color: #89a000'>123</span>!");
```

And in DOM, same as what you had:

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="htmlString"></div>
```

Comment: Isn't there another way? Preferably from withing the DOM itself. This one doesn't end up clean in my situation.

Comment: Apart from completely disabling $sce http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce#example_can-i-disable-sce-completely (not recommended), there isn't a build-in way to handle this within the DOM itself that I'm aware of. Pretty sure you should be able to get this done writing your own custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own custom directive that will have the html as `template` or reference it with `templateUrl`. Within the html you can use [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle) to add an object as your style.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tomepejo/5AsQE/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular), couse ngSanitize whitelists are not flexible ( see this issues for more details: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5900)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.