# AngularJS and TinyMCE editor - colors not binding properly

Tags: angularjs, tinymce

I've added the color plugin to my `TinyMCE` instance.

```
plugins: "textcolor",
toolbar: "forecolor backcolor"
```

I'm using the `ng-bind-html` attribute to add the tinyMCE editor content to an element. Altought, the result doesn't show as expected, because I'm adding a color into the editor, but it's not reflected to the element with the `ng-bind-html` attribute.

This is the result:
[image]

The generated HTML is this:

```
<p>TESTING <span style="color: #ff0000;">COLORED</span> CONTENT</p>
```

Do you guys have any idea how to reflect the colors to the binding element?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On setup you can call NodeChange event:

```
setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('NodeChange', function (e) {
        ed.save();
        updateView(e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been years since you asked this question, but I had the same problem today.
The inline colors are actually saved properly to the ng-model variable, but ng-bind-html strips the inline styles from its output.

The solution is found here: [AngularJS: Bind html string with custom style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503588/angularjs-bind-html-string-with-custom-style)

Load the $sce service in your controller constructor, and create this controller function:

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = function(string) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
};
```

And output the html like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(htmlString)"></div>
```

Then all the colors should show.