# Angular writing html to view using scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a html value inside my scope, i need to append it inside a div, how do i do that?

Example:

```
$scope.htmlValue = '<p> text text <\p>'; 

Html : 

<div> {{ htmlValue }} <\div>
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using AngularJS correctly. If you need to modify the HTML, you should probably be in a directive.

That being said, you need to tell angular ahead of time what can be trusted as html and then you can use the ng-bind-html directive to bind to html. You will need to use $sce.trustAsHtml(). [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu).

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is $sanitize service.
take a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

However, as has been already meantioned, it is very likely you are not using angularJS in expected way.