# $sce.trustAsHtml() filters out img

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Using a solution I found in a related question ( [How do you use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular 1.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu/19705096#19705096))

The Filter answer on that page seems to be best.

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

My images appear in IE 10, however they don't appear in Chrome or Safari.  Can someone please help me understand why?  To see my dilemma,go to http://groceryads.com and select a city from the dropdown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be an issue with angular, but css. If after selecting a city I run the following in dev tools I see your images just fine (Chrome):

```
$('#ifrss').contentWindow.window.$('img').css({width:100,height:100,maxWidth:'none'});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Jack.  My css doesn't have any img related formatting, other than this:

img.float {
 float: left;
 margin: 5px 15px 10px 0;
 border: 5px solid #A33000;
}

I see what you see in dev tools.  I tried to add your jquery at the end of my dropdown event, however it doesn't seem to fix my issue.  I'm still puzzled.

Comment: @JoeMitchell Most of my snippet is for accessing the iframe. Assuming your code is actually running in the iframe you'd want to drop the first part and just do `$('img').css({width:100,height:100,maxWidth:'none'});`

Comment: '@Jack, adding img {max-width:none;} to my css works.  Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.