# Can I prevent ng-repeat from html encoding / escaping my content in AngularJS 1.2? Or need to write own directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-encode

How can I prevent ng-repeat from html encoding / escaping my content in AngularJS 1.2? Do I need to write my own directive? I've read that `ng-bind-html-unsafe` was deprecated in Angular 1.2, but I haven't found conclusive information in regards to **using it with ng-repeat**. Some info has said to use ng-bind-html, but that didn't work either.

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in blogEntries" ng-bind-html-unsafe="entry.title">
    <div class="well">
        <div>{{entry.date }}</div> {{entry.title}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in some of my text being displayed as the following, instead of the HTML rendering:

```
<ul> <li>Blah1 5.1<li> <li>Blah 3<li></ul>
```

I also tried `ng-bind-html`

I can upgrade if necessary

Do I need to use the ng-sanitize module in order to use `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: `ng-repeat` sets in the inner html and `ng-bind` also sets the inner html so I don't think it makes sense to have them both...

Comment: This is a duplicate. See previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Comment: @jpillora ng-bind-html didn't work. if it's a dupe, please provide answer

Comment: I could copy and paste the answer I linked, though that would be cheating. Basically, it's how to use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directive `ng-bind-html` works but I had to include the sanitize module. I.e.

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    ...    
}]);

<div ng-repeat="entry in blogEntries">
    <div class="well">
        <div>{{entry.date}}</div><span ng-bind-html="entry.title"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Including that module (in 1.2) is correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs