# How to display &nbsp; or any raw html in angular data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I display `&nbsp;` as space not as string. Is there `raw` filter like in twig?

```
<div>{{item}}</div>

$scope.item = '&nbsp;';
```

But the result is escaped `&amp;nbsp;`. I need this because `' '` have height of 0.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan it was original answer I've mark and it first one that was correct. Still not sure which one should I mark as the answer.

Comment: @jcubic i have given much more detailed regarding old and new angular versions with that right

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It can be easily done by using **[ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)**

**For Angular above 1.2.x version:**

use `ng-bind-html`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J4nRK/)**

html

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
   <div ng-bind-html="item"></div>
</div>
```

script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $sce) {
   $scope.item = 'What&nbsp;Is&nbsp;Your&nbsp;Name?';
});
```

---

**For Angular 1.0.x version:**

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bT85X/)**

use `ng-bind-html-unsafe`

html

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
   <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="item"></div>
</div>
```

script

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope) {
   $scope.item = 'What&nbsp;Is&nbsp;Your&nbsp;Name?';
});
```

Comment: almost there: `$scope.item = $sce.trustAsHtml('What&nbsp;Is&nbsp;Your&nbsp;Name?');`

Comment: @domokun You should not edit someone else question with better answer (you can only fix typos, formatting, grammars etc. but not change the answer). If you have better one just create an anwser.

Comment: @jcubic Ok, sorry. The fact is that now the answer that OP selected as correct, is plain wrong...

Comment: @domokun Both answers work for me in 1.2. If you have answer that work for 1.3, you can add new answer.

Comment: @jcubic done, even though it feels weird to have the answer split like this.

Answer (score 19):

**For Angular 1.3.x version:**

Use the `$sce` service to mark the string as safe to use in a specific context (HTML in this case).
See the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce)

HTML code:

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Controller">
   <div ng-bind-html="item"></div>
</div>
```

JS code (controller):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $sce) {
   $scope.item = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span>Some HTML code</span>');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
<div data-ng-bind-html="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a filter for that.

**Filter**

```
app.filter("trustHtmlContent", ['$sce', $sce => htmlCode => $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode)]);
```

**usage**

```
<ANY ng-bind-html="value | trustHtmlContent"></ANY>
```

src: [How do you use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular 1.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu)

Comment: Isn't it suppose to be `"value | trustHtmlContent"`?

Comment: And how the url you linked is related to angular?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ascii code for &nbsp in a string.
Alt-255.

This will correctly render as an &nbsp.

Comment: This was not the question how to insert non breaking space character in AngularJS but how to add html entities like `&lt;`, `&gt;` or `&nbsp;` it's obvious that you can insert any character into text.