# Cant get a message text to render an emoji rather than the HTML text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am using a cool little AngularJS filter for emoji characters located at: http://dev.venntro.com/angular-emoji-filter/ and this is my code I have so far.

```
<p class="chatmessage plain ng-binding" ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index" ng-model="message" ng-bind-html-unsafe="message | emoji">
    <b>{{message.Author}}:</b>{{message.Message|emoji}}
</p>
```

It gives me the following output:

```
User123: <i class='emoji emoji_smiley'>smiley</i>
```

obviously, I'd rather have the emoji icon, but that is what gets output to the page. This is almost a win for me even at this stage as I had to figure out how to add all of the appropriate references to get the message filter to work and get this far. Now I am trying to come up with a way to make the "message.Message" render the HTML rather than just giving me the HTML code itself.

I am wondering if there is a function that I can wrap around that to force it to render this emoji rather than the HTML?

Thank you for any help

Sincerely,
New kid to AngularJS

Comment: Your html is being escaped. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657386/how-to-display-nbsp-or-any-raw-html-in-angular-data

Comment: it would be `<b>{{message.Author}}:</b><span ng-bind="{{message.Message|emoji}}"></span>` I think

Comment: can you provide messages array to check values ?

Comment: @ranakrunal9: I do not know how to pull an array out of Chrome's dev tools. I am very new to this as I am normally a .NET developer.

Comment: @Ludo: I tried that and it did not work for me. It is not breaking the page or anything, but it is bringing back a blank span.

Comment: use console.log in your js file to print it in console. Have you try with by applying my below answer changes ?

Comment: Here is an imgur link to what the array looks like: https://i.imgur.com/oz5S0mT.jpg

Comment: Also, here is the output on the page: https://i.imgur.com/JqyZiX5.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to try with below ng-repeat code :

```
<p class="chatmessage plain" ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index">
    <b>{{message.Author}}:</b><p ng-bind-html-unsafe="message.Message | emoji"></p>
</p>
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave me a blank <p> area. It did not break the page, but that is all it gave me.

Comment: message.Message contain string value or HTML ?

Comment: The array looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/oz5S0mT.jpg   and the output looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/JqyZiX5.jpg so it does appear that the Filter is sort of doing its job and changing that text. Its not being rendered as an emoji on the webpage.

Comment: try to use "ng-bind-html" instead of "ng-bind-html-unsafe".

Comment: include https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.min.js js file and try after adding module "ngSanitize" like angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize']) in your js. check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml