# Angular - decode string as HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have some angular expressions that contain data coming from a database. Some of this data contain HTML tags in the database and should be decoded as such in the HTML.

Javascript function:

```
vm.showTechnicalSupport = function () {
        $http.get('Navigation/GetTechSupportInformation').success(function (data) {
            vm.techSupportHours = data.techSupportHours;
        })

    }
```

HTML:

```
<span>{{ vm.techSupportHours}}</span>
```

The problem is techSupportHours is displaying raw HTML tags instead of rendering markup.
For example, there are br tags being displayed visibly on the page. Is there a way to modify my angular expression to decode this data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display &nbsp; or any raw html in angular data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657386/how-to-display-nbsp-or-any-raw-html-in-angular-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a directive called [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) which is what you are looking for.
So just change your html template to be:

```
<span ng-bind-html="vm.techSupportHours"></span>
```

Comment: Nothing is displaying when I use this directive.

Comment: @noclist Pleas ensure you also include `angular-sanitize`, it's part of Angular but not included in the core angular.js.
You can see a working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/oS492EJ0OujuC9M0Vt1V?p=preview