# Angular is not displaying encoded value in scope variables correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

could anyone help me to understand why the angular displays differently the following:

```
$scope.namea = "&amp;";
...
{{namea}}    ==> This is displayed as &amp;
{{&amp;}}    ==> This is displayed as &
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz82cpdf/) showing the problem.

Any advice on why the variable values are not decoded would be great.
I do not expect an answer how to display it correctly as it has already been answered ([How to display &nbsp; or any raw html in angular data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657386/how-to-display-nbsp-or-any-raw-html-in-angular-data)).

I want to find out why Angular behaves this way.

Thanks!

Comment: The reason is that `{{...}}` is synonym for [`ngBind` and interprets the text content](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind), not the HTML content. Even plain JavaScript will tell you that the text content for `&amp;` is `&`: Add this to your fiddle: `alert(document.querySelector("div").textContent);`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It makes sense to me now.