# Angular $sce.trustAsHtml filters out PHP code

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe with $sce.trustAsHtml as a filter, as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19705096/1463434)

When I try to pass a text such as:

```
"Code: <?php echo strtotime($user->created_at)*1000; ?>"
```

it gets rendered as:

```
"Code: created_at)*1000; ?>"
```

How do I get the whole text rendered?

**UPDATE:**

My code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<p ng-bind-html="message.messagebody | newlines | unsafe"></p>
```

Filters:

```
app.filter('newlines', function () {
  return function (text) {
    return text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  }
})

app.filter('unsafe', ['$sce',
  function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    }
  }
])
```

I am using ng-bind-html so that whenever a new line is entered, it is converted into a "<br/>" tag and displayed as a new line when rendered in the browser.

Comment: why do you use trustAsHtml? i what happens if you just past the text as is?

Comment: **`<`** isn't valid html, try converting to htmlentities or create your own directive to set the html so it isn't being run through `$sce`

Comment: When a user enters a new line character it needed to be converted into <br/> tag so that the new line is reflected when rendered in the browser. Otherwise it comes in the same line. This is why I have used ng-bind-html instead of ng-bind.

Comment: old q, have you solve it on your own @Prateek Bhatt ?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webadnan/6uuy3/).

Simply use angular variable in html.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
    <h3>Not worked</h13>
    <pre>Code: <?php echo strtotime($user->created_at)*1000; ?></pre>

    <h3>Worked</h3>
    <pre>{{data.html}}</pre>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TestController', function($scope){
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.html = "Code: <?php echo strtotime($user->created_at)*1000; ?>";
});
```

Comment: this will not work when i use ng-bind-html instead of using angular variable. It will throw an error.

Comment: The example I posted worked for me. So, do not use ng-bind-html then.

Comment: I know your example works. However, I need to use ng-bind-html for a different purpose: to convert newlines to break-tags and render them as html. Is there a way to make it work with ng-bind-html ?