# how to avoid double encoding with $sce

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Angular $sce service seems to be encoding characters and *not* trusting the html. Is there an option to have the html trusted?

```
$scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml('it&#39;s broken')
```

An example.

```
<p>it&#39;s working</p>
<p>{{ text }}</p>
```

Looks like.

```
it's working
it&#39;s broken
```

I'd rather not use `ng-bind-html` because it's meant to be used in a filter like the following.

```
{{ text | render }}
```

Comment: You need to use ng-bind-html since ng-bind-html-unsafe no longer exists. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19705096/1336081

Comment: Edited. I want to use it in a filter is the thing.

Comment: Could you explain the rational behind using a filter? Thanks

Comment: Maybe a filter is wrong, but the idea is to render a tweet from the raw tweet text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the `$sce` that encode your html, actually nothing does that.

But when you use an interpolation `{{ text }}`, angular will detect that and replace it with a correct value via `textNode.nodeValue`, not something like `innerHTML`. Therefore, your `&#39;` will be treated as a normal text, not an encoded HTML entity.

That's why the `ng-bind-html` exists, and nothing prevent you from using the filter inside the `ng-bind-html` expression.

```
<div ng-bind-html="text | render | trustAsHtml"></div>
```

Example filters:

```
.filter('render', function () {
  return function (value) {
    return value + '!';
  };
})

.filter('trustAsHtml', function ($sce) {
  return function (value) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
  };
})
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/F8OQvoSzOR06TPepc2Fo?p=preview