# Preserving line breaks in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an app that uses AngularJS. My controller looks like this:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.lines = 'var x=1;\nvar y=2;';
}
```

My view looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <p>
    Output:<br />
    <code>{{lines}}</code>
  </p>
</div>
```

When the view is rendered, the value in `$scope.lines` is rendered on a single line like this:

```
var x=1; var y=2;
```

However, I want to display it as:

```
var x=1;
var y=2;
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried switching `\n` with `<br />`, however, that did not work either.

Comment: Is the code-tag working as a pre-tag? `white-space: pre;`?

Comment: this works, based on a deleted answer here http://jsfiddle.net/zbvnqmyd/

Answer (score 3):

So far, the only way to do it would be using `ng-bind-html` (`-unsafe`) (check your angular version because you might need to use `$sce`) to bind HTML to an element, like this:

---

### Angular 1.0.X:

```
<code ng-bind-html-unsafe="lines"></code>
```

---

### Angular 1.2+:

```
<code ng-bind-html="lines"></code>
```

but it needs `$sce`:

```
$scope.lines = $sce.trustAsHtml('var x=1;<br />var y=2;');
```

---

And of course, use the HTML line break: `<br />`

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3fha088t/

Same example here as a snippet:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.lines = 'var x=1;<br />var y=2;';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <p>Working version: </p>
        <code ng-bind-html-unsafe="lines"></code>
      <p>Original version: </p>
      <code>{{lines}}</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angular 1.2 version, using $sce:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.lines = $sce.trustAsHtml('var x=1;<br />var y=2;');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <p>Working version: </p>
        <code ng-bind-html="lines"></code>
      <p>Original version: </p>
      <code>{{lines}}</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using /n as in the original question, it's likely that @JimmyRare's solution of adding "white-space: pre;" to the css will fix this

Comment: @BenTaliadoros Yeah, but it's usually a good idea to stick to one way of making line breaks. Since OP is already using `<br>` in his view (rather than `<pre>content</pre>`), he should probably stick with HTML line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

your $scope.lines are replaced as plain string. you should bind it as html instead.

see this [How do you use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular 1.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu)