# AngularJs - html rendering

Tags: html, angularjs, highlighting

We use elastic search highlighter and get the below code from the highlighter.

```
<span style='font-weight:bold;color:red;'>Baskar</span> Test
```

We display the result in html as follows.

```
                     <tr
                        ng-repeat="result in searchModelResult">                        
                        <td><p ng-bind-html="result.name"></p></td>                     
                    </tr>
```

I have included sanitize.js and have ngSanitize in the angular module. Still i dont see the html effect like red color font and bold font.

Am i missing anything here?

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things, first remove

```
{{result.name}}
```

as Daniel said... then you need to say to angular to trust in that html in your controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.result.name = $sce.trustAsHtml('<span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;">Baskar</span> Test');
});
```

You can see the full documentation of $sce [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

If you need to iterate inside a ng-repeat you can create a filter:

```
myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

And then use it in the view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in searchModelResult">                        
    <td><p ng-bind-html="result.name | unsafe"></p></td>                     
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi,
  I am getting a list and iterating using ng-repeat in the html. Should I iterate the list in the controller and add  $sce.trustAsHtml for each element?

Comment: not necessarily, you can create a filter as Chris said in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu see the second answer (the one witch has 306 points). Tell me if you need an example.

Comment: @user1578872 I put an example on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the second binding expression:

```
{{result.name}}
```

It looks like that is overriding the binding from `ng-bind-html`, and the default binding will HTML escape the string.

Comment: I tried this. Now, i dont see the html tags. But i dont see the html effect. Text color is still in normal color not in red and not in bold.