# Trying to output html with angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to output html with angular js. I know the html is going to be ok.
This is what im trying now:

```
<div class="items-list" id="items-container">
        <div ng-repeat="data in ItemsData track by $index" ng-bind-html='ItemsData'>
            <-data->
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is what i pretty much am doing with the data

```
$.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "{{URL::route('items')}}",
                        data: filteringData,
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }
            ).done(function (response) {
                        $scope.ItemsData = $sce.trustAsHtml(response['items']);
                        $scope.ItemsPage += 1;
                        $scope.ItemsLastPage = response['lastPage'];
                        $scope.ItemsLoaderBusy = false;
                    });
```

But this is not working. Im trying to do this for a long time.

Pretty much what I want is that I get a response from the server. It has 'items'. Its an array of elements that are html. How could I output them with a repeat?

And I really dont know what im doing. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Can you check the console?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, Im getting this Uncaught Error: [$sce:itype] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$sce/itype?p0=html I know it is something to do with the trusted html thing. But I dont understand why. How should it work then.

Comment: I'm confused by the code you have written here.  If `$scope.ItemsData` is an HTML string, then how could you iterate over it with `ng-repeat`?  Can you post some sample of what you are receiving in the function, and the output you are expecting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Comment: No,no. ItemsData is actually an array that has html string data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `data` variable which you have defined in `ng-repeat` for binding inside `ng-bind-html`. So change `ItemsData` to `data`.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in ItemsData track by $index" ng-bind-html='data'>
   <-data->
</div>
```

Also as you commented to the question you are getting error when executing `$sce.trustAsHtml` method, it is because you are passing an array `response['items']`when it expects a string.

Assuming `response['items']` as an array of string you can try this.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "{{URL::route('items')}}",
    data: filteringData,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(response) {
    $scope.ItemsData = [];
    angular.forEach(response.items, function(item) {
       $scope.ItemsData.push($sce.trustAsHtml(item));
    });
    $scope.ItemsPage += 1;
    $scope.ItemsLastPage = response['lastPage'];
    $scope.ItemsLoaderBusy = false;
});
```

Also as pointed by @pankajparkar you should try to use $http instead of jQuery ajax because it will run the digest cycle.

Comment: Alright, the error is gone now. Now I need to only change it to use angular http to work right?

Comment: I made another update to the answer ..take a look and update in your code accordingly... then you should be good to go.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU VERY MUCH! I HAVE BEEN DOING THIS FOR MORE THEN A COUPLE OF HOURS AND COULDN'T GET IT TO WORK! Btw, its not yelling caps locks its Happiness caps locks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79702/discussion-between-davelv2-and-shankarsangoli).

Answer (score 2):

You should never have been use `$.ajax`, that should be replaced the ajax call using `$http` service. Using `$.ajax` will not run digest cycle on its completion where `$http` does run digest cycle after callback gets called

Additionally your ng-bind would be `ng-bind-html="trustedAsHtml(data)"`

then your controller will have one method `trustedAsHtml` that will html as trusted using `$sce` service

`$scope.trustedAsHtml = function(data){
   return $sce.trustedAsHtml(data);
}`

Comment: @davelv2 this must have helpful to you..:)

Comment: @pankajpakar Your right too. So thanks for the help! :)

Comment: does that $sce part was helpful??

Comment: I used the other one in the selected answer.