# Security features in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi i would like to know about the security features of angular js.I have read that angular provide built in protection from basic security holes.

1. It Prevents cross-side-scripting attacks.
2. Prevents HTML injection attacks.
3. Prevent XSRF protection for server side communication.

what are the best practice to make a secured angular app, does ngCsp,$sce and $sanitize are really required for a secured webapp

Comment: This is too broad a question without some kind of use case. The angular features described in that article are great, but there are ways you can bypass those features if you don't know what you are doing with JS. Please add a use case with code to help demonstrate it, and a more applicable answer can be provided.

Comment: @Ben Rondeau thanks for your response, i just want to add a basic level of security to my app without make it slower which will include all the three points which i have stated above.If you can provide some example or some   article for reference it would be a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable AngularJS [CSP](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp) support. More details here. Sample code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app ng-csp>
...
...
</html>
```

`ng-csp` forces you not use code that can be injected like `eval` and `Function`.
ng-sanitize from [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize).

> The input is sanitized by parsing the HTML into tokens. All safe
>   tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to properly escaped
>   html string. This means that no unsafe input can make it into the
>   returned string, however, since our parser is more strict than a
>   typical browser parser, it's possible that some obscure input, which
>   would be recognized as valid HTML by a browser, won't make it through
>   the sanitizer. The input may also contain SVG markup. The whitelist is
>   configured using the functions `aHrefSanitizationWhitelist` and
>   `imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist` of $`compileProvider`.

It simply you can not attach any peace of code using innerHTML.

For $sce, you can refer following links.
[TrustasHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu) and and its nice [tutorial](http://learnwebtutorials.com/using-angularjs-sce-trustashtml-raw-html).

Apart from this, you can use auth token.

Edit: You can verify the input in [backend](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Input-Validation.html) to make sure no injection have been made.