# Rendering HTML as it appears in the database in to a view using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I am using TinyMCE to style content that the user then saves to the database, an example of what the user could be saving is as below:

```
<ol><li><em>This</em> is a <span style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;">HTML</span> email that <strong><span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times;">should</span></strong> <span style="font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">contain</span> different <span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">fonts</span> in weights with lists and links...</li></ol>
```

I am currently using `ng-bind-html` to display this HTML content in my view, however, it appears to be stripping the inline styles. Here is my source from the browser:

```
<ol><li><em>This</em> is a <span>HTML</span> email that <strong><span>should</span></strong> <span>contain</span> different <span>fonts</span> in weights with lists and links...</li></ol>
```

Is there a way in which I can keep these inline styles in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try marking your HTML as trusted, passing in [$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsHtml), as:

```
yourApp.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {      
  $scope.some_html = $sce.trustAsHtml(some_html_content);
}]);
```

Comment: Could this be implemented into a filter? So for example I could have in my html {{ message.body | trustHtml }} ?

Comment: @SeriousJelly yes, check this answer:: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19705096/350858

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular 1.2+ you have do this:

```
$scope.htmlToBind = $sce.trustAsHtml(yourHtml);
```

See [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce#example) for more details.