# $sce.trustAsHtml Fails on a String

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run `$sce.trustAsHtml` on a string. It throws [Error: $sce:itype
String Value is Required for SCE Trust Call](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/itype?p0=html) even though I'm using it on a function that returns a string.

Here's a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/frllqX?p=preview) and the snippet causing the error.

```
/*****
 * Should display two images
 * *****/
$scope.image = determineNeverSettleImage("engaging,innovative");
$scope.image = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.image);

/************
 * This function should:
 *  return 3 images if passed "engaging,innovating,partnering",
 *  return 2 images if passed "engaging,innovating",
 *  return 1 image if passed "engaging"
 **************/
function determineNeverSettleImage(neverSettle) {
  if (neverSettle.split(",").length > 1) {
    neverSettleArray = neverSettle.split(",");
    neverSettleStr = "";
    for (i = 0; i < neverSettleArray.length; i++) {
      if (neverSettleArray[i] == "engaging") {
        neverSettleStr += '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
      }
      if (neverSettleArray[i] == "innovating") {
        neverSettleStr += '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
      }
      if (neverSettleArray[i] == "partnering") {
        neverSettleStr += '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
      }
      if (neverSettleArray[i] == "synergy") {
        neverSettleStr += '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
      }
    }
    $scope.test = neverSettleStr;
    neverSettleStr = neverSettleStr + '';
    return neverSettleStr;
  } else {
    switch (neverSettle) {
      case "engaging":
        neverSettle = '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
        return neverSettle;
      case "innovating":
        neverSettle = '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
        return neverSettle;
      case "partnering":
        neverSettle = '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
        return neverSettle;
      case "synergy":
        neverSettle = '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="56px" height="56px">';
        return neverSettle;
    }
  }
}
```

Perhaps there is something wrong with my logic? Or am I using `$sce.trustAsHtml` incorrectly somehow?

Comment: This might be a good reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having an issue because you're assigning `$scope.image` a value and then trusting it. Try:

```
$scope.image =  $sce.trustAsHtml(determineNeverSettleImage("engaging,innovative"));
```

As a side note, if you are wanting to pull in a resource, you should be using `trustAsResourceUrl`, which you could then use in an `ngRepeat`. Just so you know you have options.

```
$scope.image = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks @Caleb, I'll try this when I have the time again.