# ngTransclude breaks HTML content rendering in custom directives, even with $sce.trustAsHtml() filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am having trouble getting transcluded content to render properly in my custom directives.

Here are examples:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mvx5GuMrPcUPJbrOCKbD

The content coming from the external source has newline (`\n`) characters, and I want to use a filter to replace the newlines with `<br>` HTML tags.

```
app.filter('newline2br_trust', ['$sce',
    function($sce) {
        return function(input) {
          return input ? $sce.trustAsHtml(input.replace(/\n/g, '\n<br/>')) : '';
        };
    }
]);
```

This seems to work correctly if I use ng-bind-html on a single element, but if I have a custom directive with transcluded contents, it seems to ignore the $sce.trustAsHtml(), and escapes the HTML content:

```
<multiline>{{ example.data1 | newline2br_trust }}</multiline>
```

How can I get my directive to properly transclude this HTML content?

NOTE: It seems to be something with the $sce functionality with AngularJS expressions + ngTransclude, as raw/static HTML content works properly with transclude:

```
<multiline>BrLine1<br/>BrLine2<br/>BrLine3</multiline>
```

Comment: Try using `<multiline ng-bind-html="{{ example.data1 | newline2br_trust }}"></multiline>`

Comment: Yes, if you take a look at the plunkr, `ng-bind-html` works, except I want this directive to work with ALL transcluded content.  The `<br>` tags work if the raw HTML is transcluded, but not if the HTML comes from an expression, even if that expression ends with a filter that outputs `$sce.trustAsHtml` content.

Comment: Anything here help you at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu/18342738#18342738

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm looking for a solution using ngTransclude.

Comment: @thaMANSTA did you ever solve this?