# How to render HTML input tag in AngularJS from a HTML string returned from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

Actually I am trying to send a string from PHP which has some HTML elements. The `div` element of that HTML is rendering fine, but all `input` elements of HTML are not rendering. How can I achieve that

Here is my PHP function:

```
function testHtml(){
    $html = 'heeeeeer test <div class="abc"> abccc test....
        <input type="text" name="aaa" ng-model="rec.aaa"> 
    </div>  ';
    echo '{"result" :'.json_encode($html).'}';
}
```

Here is my HTML & Angular code:

```js
$scope.testHtml = $resource('api/item/testHtml').get(function(data){
 $scope.testhtmls =  data.result;
});
```

```html
 <div class="" ng-bind-html="testhtmls">
   
 </div>
```

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$sce` service before passing it to `ng-bind-html`:

```
$scope.testhtmls =  $sce.trustAsHtml(data.result);
```