# Unsafe Error is coming in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting this error when I am trying to implement Select dropdown already running in here. http://flatfull.com/themes/flatkit/html/form.select.html

Error image is below
[image]

My Html part is this

```
<div class="col-sm-6 dr_search" tabindex="-1" id="dr_search">
          <ui-select ng-model="user_prefix.selected" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Title">{[{$select.selected.data_key_value}]}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in people | filter: $select.search" ng-model="user_prefix">
              <div ng-bind-html="item.data_key_value | highlight: $select.search"></div>

            </ui-select-choices>
          </ui-select>

        </div>
```

Ajax calling while loading response is below

```
{"name_prefix":[{"data_key_value":"Mr."},{"data_key_value":"Mrs."}]}
```

No error while loading but when I click to search or try to select this error is coming.

I am assigning response getting from ajax

```
$scope.people = data.name_prefix;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS need to trust to each `html` that you try to bind anywhere, thats' why
you need to use

[that provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

[answer for your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342738/2500040)

If you pass not the `html` to the view, then use `ng-bind` instead.