# Using replace in "<br>"

Tags: angularjs, html

Im trying to show a text in the screen using:

```
{{content.lore}}
```

so far ok, but my text is formatted like this:

"...`<br><br>`Essa criação poderosa - forjada à imagem de uma gárgula - o manteve`<br><br>` seguro em suas jornadas, permitindo que ele desempenhasse seu importante trabalho sem medo de retaliações daqueles hostis à sua terra natal.`<br><br>` Isso é, até despertar a ira do Alto Comando Noxiano com suas sentinelas.`<br><br>`...".

These `<br>` are showed in the text and i want to delete it. Using

```
content.lore.replace("<br>", "");
```

the text don't change. How can i replace these `<br>`?

Comment: You might want to use `ng-bind-html` - here is the documentation for that. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce - Angular by default escapes all HTML, so you have to either mark the source as trusted, or disable this in angular.

Comment: Also, I think this answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a filter that converts html to text if you want to remove the `<br>`

```
app.filter('htmlToText', function(){
  return function(html){        
     return angular.element('<div>').append(html || '').text();
  };
});
```

View

```
{{content.lore | htmlToText}}
```