# limit the length of a text using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the `limitTo` filter in my angularJs application.

I have a div which displays a parsed html code as following :

```
<div ng-bind-html="o.description | filter:unsafe | filter:limitTo:50"></div>
```

but the `limitTo` filter didn't work.

How can I solve this problem ?

## Edit :

due to @hadiJZ response I changed my div to this :

but still it doesn't work, when I tried to apply the limitTo filter on another div it worked, and this is an example :

```
<a href="#/offres/{{o.codeOffre}}">{{o.titre | limitTo:2}}</a>
```

the `unsafe` filter :

```
myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
  return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. your syntax is incorrect. not to need use filter in here.

```
 <div ng-bind-html="o.description | unsafe | limitTo:50"></div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say that it didn't work, please check the modifications I made

Comment: do you inject ngSanitize in your app?

Comment: Of course I did otherwise the html code wont be parsed

Comment: this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu