# Read HTML Code from Database in MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs

I'm writing a web page and I use Angularjs to load HTML code saved in database but it just show like a string not active HTML code. How could I solve this problem? Thanks for your attention.
This is my code in php file.

```
<td>{{uni.level_name}}</td>
<td>{{uni.entry_requirements}}</td>
```

And this is the problem.
[image: Problem when load HTML code saved in database]

Comment: Hi, kindly go to View Source and show me how it was written there..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

Comment: @AKZhang thanks for your reply, the source code from many people so I do not know where it was written. My task is just finding out the way to load HTML code from database and it will run normally not show original code like in the picture. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Terminus thanks for your help, that is not my problem because my HTML code saved and loaded from database not from any file in the project

Comment: `uni.entry_requirements` must be encoded with `http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php` or something similar.  Is the source `&lt;h4%gt;`?

Comment: @JeongAe You're welcome! I think if you add the `trust` filter to your angular module and then mosify your html to look like so `<td>{{uni.level_name | trust}}</td>
<td>{{uni.entry_requirements | trust}}</td>` your problem will be solved. The reason being, [angular escapes any html code you try to display automatically](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: @chris85 thanks for your answer, but I tried to use it and it's still not working.

Comment: @Terminus Thanks you very much! That's my problem and 'trust' can help me to solve that. In my situation, I use 'trust' like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29225894/4758114 and I can solve the problem.

Comment: @JeongAe excellent! Just be aware of the danger of trusting user html (read about [cross site scripting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). If the wiki isn't helpful, please do look around for another resource that explains it to your satisfaction)

Answer (score 1):

Use [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml):

```
<td ng-bind-html="uni.level_name"></td>
```