# How to convert a string in a html element?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a column in a DB which has the value:

```
<p>Something</p>
```

When i receive it, how do i transform it in a html paragraph?
Thanks!

Comment: that _is_ a paragraph.

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried? How is it not already an HTML paragraph? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular 1.2+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu)

Answer (score 1):

As if the string is a HTML entity, you can use [`jQuery.parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) like this:

```
var element = $.parseHTML("<p>Something</p>");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var stringInDB = '<p>Something</p>'; //get the string
$('#target').html(stringInDB);       //set the content (the string as html) of the elemtn where you want to put that string
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"> <div/> <!-- where you want to put you string as html -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular (which it looks like from the tagging) you could always include ngSanitize and bind the scope element in your template:

```
<div ng-bind-html="ctrl.stringProperty">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i am. And i want to convert the string which is an html paragraph and is stored in a controller variable....i just cant get it -.- @sledsworth

Comment: Thx for the help! It is done! ng-bind-html works perfectly! Thanks a lot! :) @sledsworth