# AngularJS and uncomfortable filtering in ng-repeat (non English character)

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

In the MySQL database I have names with non-English characters.
For example: 'Guerneca','G**ú**stav','G**ü**nther',

It is uncomfortable if I want to filter using the function:

**JS**

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    if(input) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    };
    return [];
}
});
```

input in **PHP**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-change="filter()" placeholder="Filter" class="form-control" />
```

And I will begin to write ***gu*** the expected selection is all three names (Guernica, Gústav, Günther), but in my case I get only the name **Guernica**

I've also tried this page, but it did not help: [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_input)

Also characters **o** for (**ó,ô,ö**) or **r** for (**ŕ,ř**) etc....

Interestingly, that small and capital letters are not sensitive.

Can you any help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support greek letter. Go for angular table they are much more performance efficient and provide you with lot's of other feature.