# Space Between Text In Same JSON String

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am volunteering to write a quick AngularJS App for a non-profit. I have set up Angular successfully but the one problem I am coming across stems from the JSON.

I have a JSON object that contains multiple paragraphs. Therefore I need to separate the paragraphs onto two lines. I did some research and I found some answers to similar questions but because they were not put in context I did not understand them. I tried looking to see if JSON had something built in that forced a line break, because that would do, but I did not find that.

Help is greatly appreciated!

**HTML w/ Angular JS**

```
<div class="bio">
    {{exhibits[whichItem].bio}}
</div>
```

**JSON**

```
[
  {
    "name":"Name goes here",
    "bio":"First long block of text goes here then it needs a break <br /> and the second long block of text is here."
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu

Comment: I just took a look at that question. I do not understand the question or the answer and I am looking for something more in-line and explanatory to my current situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@user5854648 Your back-end sending the JSON response in this format .If you are using angular version greater than  1.2 to display the text content with html tags(People's calling this as unsafe html ) use angularjs inbuilt service called $sce .To make it as a reusable component  created a custom filter.

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',[]);
demoApp.filter('trustAsHtml', [
    '$sce',
    function($sce) {
        return function(value) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml('html', value);
        }
    }
]);
```

then make changes in html like

```
<div class="bio">
    {{exhibits[whichItem].bio | trustAsHtml}}
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="bio">
        <p ng-bind='exhibits[whichItem].bio | trustAsHtml'></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Snowp, I feel like I am close but I am missing a concept here that is preventing it from working. I see that the return $sce.trustAsHtml ('html', value); is printing exactly html as a string. I'm not sure how to call the JSON file here that shows the appropriate JSON text being called which is {{exhibits[whichItem].bio}}. I don't know what to type in your example to exactly pull that which is within the brackets.

Comment: Did  you are asking about how to display json response ?

Comment: I can get the JSON to display, but it displays with the HTML tags rather than styling the HTML. So if I were to wrap something in <b></b> it wouldn't appear bold, it was literally show the tags around the text.