# Dynamically Import Component From Variable (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm trying to load a component based off of a variable but I get a "Uncaught Error: Template parse errors". How would I go about doing something like this?

```
<app-{{ this.plugin.component }}></app-{{ this.plugin.component }}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible to do it on template, but you certainly can do it on your controller/component try to do something like:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
var element = angular.element('<app' + variable + '></app' + variable + '>');
element = $compile(element)(scope);
```

To print the element in your template you'll need to use `$sce`:

[How do you use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular 1.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu)

Answer (score 0):

Have to add each path manually to the "app.module" but everything seems to operate by using child paths. Wish there was a way to more dynamically use components with the tags but this will work for what I'm doing now.

```
{
    path: 'mypath', 
    component: MyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'childpath',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
}
```