# How to render dynamic data using ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

I am getting a list of object from service. I used ng-repeat to display json object data in ui.

```
<div class="agreementPopover" ng-repeat="pm in list">
                <p class="md-subhead robotoMedium bodyFontColor zeroMrgn" >{{pm.des}}</p>
                <p class="md-subhead blackColour btmMrgn" ng-bind-html="pm.html| renderHTML"></p>
            </div>
```

I created a custom filter to convert my html in trust html.

```
filter('renderHTML', ['$sce', function($sce) {
           return function(val) {
           return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
           };
           }])
```

The issue is dynamic html content is not displaying in my UI.

My Html content is

```
<a href="http://force.com/PublicKB/articles/FAQ/What-is-the-for-Program/?q=letter+of+credit&l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle" target="_blank" class="agreementPaymentLink">www.skip.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that your html value in the array to be string format as show below, also you can check this working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oj99caKZKt4PV0O8x8h8?p=preview) of your example scenario.

**Template:**

```
<div class="agreementPopover" ng-repeat="pm in list">
    <p class="md-subhead robotoMedium bodyFontColor zeroMrgn" >{{pm.des}}</p>
    <p class="md-subhead blackColour btmMrgn" ng-bind-html="pm.html| renderHTML"></p>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$http.get('sample.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.list = response.data;
});
```

Comment: In the example $scope.list is static it means you declared it in controller but in my case I am fetching $scope.list data from server. I don't know why ng-bind-html directive is not rendering my dynamic html.

Comment: Still the rule is applicable of having the html as string format. Have you checked your response html values?

Comment: There you go. I've updated my answer to have data from $http response as with dummy data. Please check..

Answer (score 0):

### Demo:

```js
angular.module("test",[]).controller("testc",function($scope,$sce) {
$scope.value= $sce.trustAsHtml('<a href="http://force.com/PublicKB/articles/FAQ/What-is-the-for-Program/?q=letter+of+credit&l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle" target="_blank" class="agreementPaymentLink">www.skip.com</a>')
      

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testc">
<p class="md-subhead blackColour btmMrgn" ng-bind-html="value"></p>
        </div>
```

### So try this

//controller

```
$scope.sce=$sce;// define `$sce` in your scope object
```

// html

```
 <p class="md-subhead blackColour btmMrgn" ng-bind-html="sce.trustAsHtml(pm.html)"></p>
```

I hope this below discussion will helps you lot

[How do you use $sce.trustAsHtml(string) to replicate ng-bind-html-unsafe in Angular 1.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu)

Answer (score 0):

- Check console for error messages
- Check your imports ( angular-sanitize )
- Check filter name for typos
- Check that module that defines the filter is included in your controller´s or components module

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('trustedFilter', ['ngSanitize'] )
  .filter('renderHTML', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
  }]);
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['trustedFilter'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myHTML = '<a href="http://force.com/PublicKB/articles/FAQ/What-is-the-for-Program/?q=letter+of+credit&l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle" target="_blank" class="agreementPaymentLink">www.skip.com</a>';
  }])
  
})(window.angular);

/*
Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-bind-html-production</title>
  

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-sanitize.js"></script>


  
</head>
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <p ng-bind-html="myHTML | renderHTML"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```