# How to generate html document using angular 1.x and allow the users to download it

Tags: java, angularjs

I have an endpoint: `getHtmlContent` in my Java code.
It returns me a String with actual HTML code e.g.: `<pre>Hello world \n Line 2 </pre>`

On my web page I have two options: View, and Download.

When the user clicks on Download, I will call `getHtmlContent` endpoint that will get me actual HTML content as String.

How do I write that response to a file such that the user is actually able to download the content as content.html file?

How do I render the View option?

Comment: [Google search for you](https://www.google.es/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GGRV_enES767ES770&ei=T8OvWu-hIaLjsAenlrWYDA&q=content+type+response+Content-Type%3A+application%2Foctet-stream+Content-Disposition%3A+attachment%3B+filename%3D"test.txt"&oq=content+type+response+Content-Type%3A+application%2Foctet-stream+Content-Disposition%3A+attachment%3B+filename%3D"test.txt"&gs_l=psy-ab.3...5787.9356.0.9505.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.P3BUgBvLSDE)

Comment: Check this link to render string as html content https://stackoverflow.com/a/18342738/2079271

Comment: This link can be useful https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: I am at a point where I did something like this : <a href ="htmlContent" ng-click ="getContent(id)" download="doc.html"> download</a>.   getContent is a function that pulls the data from my api end point. However this download attribute in <a> tag downloads a file even before I get response from my api which is stored in "htmlContent"