# src stripped from json html data when using angular.js and angular-sanitize.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm an angular noob here... but enjoying figuring it out. I have simple json file containing text like so:

```
   "gettingstarted":{
      "title":"Getting Started",
      "content":"<img ng-src='images/pageone-snorkeler.png' width='150' height='107' alt='Snorkeler' /><p>Getting Started...... and a lot of other html in here...</p>"
   },"etc..."
```

I am trying to load images into the rendered html, however, angular seems to be stripping the src and ng-src from my html.

My page.tpl.html file looks like so:

```
<h1 ng-bind-html="page.title"></h1>
<div ng-bind-html="page.content"></div>
```

I am loading / using:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

I can see all the html render in the page correctly from the json data, however, not the image. It is rendering like so:

```
<img width='150' height='107' alt='Snorkeler' />
```

What am I missing to get images to load in my html?

EDIT::::
Looks like I needed to word my question different... I found the answer here: [ng-bind-html does not load image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363437/ng-bind-html-does-not-load-image-src)

```
ng-bind-html-unsafe
```

...which isn't working for me... or use the fully resolved url: **http://superraddomainname.com/image/image.png** for example.

Comment: Found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363437/ng-bind-html-does-not-load-image-src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-bind-html-unsafe` has been removed in angular 1.2. What you've done with `ng-bind-html` should work, you have to make sure you add `ngSanitize` as a dependency in your app. For example...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
```

[**Demo - Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/deCcG/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! As long as I load it from the full URL, no problem. If i try and load locally, it doesn't show.

Comment: Just noticed that the img tag was using ng-src. Make sure that's src.